# Rust ? operator does not work with Into<T> trait

Tags: rust, traits

I was writting a function to flat a Result. This is what I got.

```rust
type BoxDyn = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>;
fn flat_result<U, T, G>(r: Result<Result<U, G>, T>) -> Result<U, BoxDyn>
where
    T: Into<BoxDyn>,
    G: Into<BoxDyn>,
{
    match r {
        Err(x) => Err(x.into()),
        Ok(x) => match x {
            Err(x) => Err(x.into()),
            Ok(x) => Ok(x),
        },
    }
}
```

It works fine. But I should be able to write it using two `?` like this.

```rust
type BoxDyn = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>;
fn flat_result<U, T, G>(r: Result<Result<U, G>, T>) -> Result<U, BoxDyn>
where
    T: Into<BoxDyn>,
    G: Into<BoxDyn>,
{
    Ok(r??)
}
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
`G` cannot be shared between threads safely
required because of the requirements on the impl of `From<G>` for `Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, G>>` for `Result<U, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>`
```

But it seems to me that it should not happen because the documentation says that the `?` `is equivalent to a match expression, where the Err(err) branch expands to an early return Err(From::from(err))`. And also `From<T> for U implies Into<U> for T`. So it would not matter What G or T are, if they implement Into it should work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that `From` implies `Into` but not that `into` implies `From`. And remember that `?` uses `From`, not `Into`.

As it happens there is this [`impl`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E-1) in the standard library that gets in the way:

```
impl<'a, E: Error + Send + Sync + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'a>
```

Since your `BoxDyn` alias is exactly that with `'a = 'static`, you have an implementation for `From<E>`. But for that to work your error types `T` and `G` has to satisfy `Error + Send + Sync + 'a`. But your only constraints are that they are `Into<Error>` that is actually unrelated to what is needed. Remember that `From` implies `Into` but `Into` does not imply `From`.

It works if you write instead:

```
fn flat_result<U, T, G>(r: Result<Result<U, G>, T>) -> Result<U, BoxDyn>
where
    T: Error + Send + Sync + 'static,
    G: Error + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    Ok(r??)
}
```

But I think that the proper way to write that would be to require the `From` trait:

```
fn flat_result<U, T, G>(r: Result<Result<U, G>, T>) -> Result<U, BoxDyn>
where
    BoxDyn: From<T> + From<G>,
{
    Ok(r??)
}
```

Why does it work with the manual implementation? Well, because you are using `Into` instead of `From` of course. Change it to `BoxDyn::from(x)` and it will fail just the same.

Comment: I didn't know I could write trait bounds for a type that wasn't generic. That was an amazing answer. Thank you very much.